# How to apply at least three days criteria for heat wave calculation

Tags: weather, cdo-climate

I want to calculate heat wave occurence on the basis of percentiles. The maximum temperature has to be greater than the 90th percentile for at least three consecutive days. How can I calculate this part using `cdo`.

I tried to solve it using the following approach

```
cdo ge infile.nc 90thpctl.nc 1.nc
cdo runsum,3 1.nc 2.nc
cdo gec,3 2.nc 3.nc 
cdo timsum 3.nc ndays.nc
```

Is this the approach to include at least three consecutive days criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if `tmax.nc` is your file of daily maximum temperature, then first of all we need to construct the heat wave event by getting a 1 for every day above your 90%tile threshold.

We need to modify those approaches to use the percentile based on the time of year to account for seasonality, so we will use the `ydaypctl` function. Often this is smoothed using a 15 day window to make things less noisy when using daily data, so I will apply a 15 day running mean.

We also need a long input file for good statistics. *I will assume that the * ***input*** *file runs from 25th December 1980, to 7th January 2011 so that* ***after*** *I apply the 15 day running mean the daily file has dates that exactly cover 1981 to 2010.*

```
# Average the tmax and then do seasonalized percentile
cdo runmean,15 tmax.nc tmax15.nc

# Threshold for the tmax
cdo ydaypctl,90 tmax15.nc -ydaymin tmax15.nc -ydaymax tmax15.nc p90.nc

# Make series with 1 for every day that exceeds the threshold:
cdo -ge tmax.nc p90.nc hwday.nc
```

Okay, so now we have a series of 1s for each day above the heatwave threshold, so now we want to look at the length of each and only keep events which are longer than 3 days, for this we can use the *consects* function

```
# Now get heatwaves
cdo consects hwday.nc hwlenall.nc

# Set any len less than 2 to zero. I assume the variable is called "tmax"
cdo -expr,'tmax = ((tmax > 2)) ? tmax : 0' hwlenall.nc hwlen3.nc

# Now you can the number of events each year
cdo yearsum -gec,3 hwlenall.nc eventsperyear.nc

# And the mean duration
cdo yearmean hwlen3.nc average_heatwave_len.nc
```

Comment: Part or most of this could be done using CDO's climate calcs, e.g. eca_hwfi, but they remain poorly documented. https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-993000B

Comment: yes you are right, I usually find they never quite calculate what i need though.